# Coexistence of Angular 4 and Angular JS 1x

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng-upgrade

We are currently working with Angular JS 1.6. Our achitecture Layers as follows,
HTML Page, 
Controller (MVC Controller), 
Service (Holds $resource for service side API),
State (Holds states for a functionality)
* Functionality is collection of HTML pages.
We are planning to migrate to Angular 4.0. Exiting project which is in Angular JS 1.6 has huge number of pages that needs to be redesign. Is it possible to develop new pages in Angular 4.0 and reuse the existing pages which are present in Angular Js 1.6..?
Can both the version coexists in a same project...?
How to achieve that..?

Answer (score 3):

There is a thing called **ngUpgrade**. Which basically doing what you are asking.

> When you use **ngUpgrade**, what you're really doing is running both
>   AngularJS and Angular at the same time.

[Here is a tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade) which explains how does it work and what are the crucial steps to use upgrade strategy.